# How configure dnsmask to keep searching the upstreams server until he found an answer

Tags: dnsmasq

I have two domain servers : one (172.25.250.254) is a private for serving private *.lab.example.com request and the other (192.168.1.1 in my box) is for serving public request like index.docker.io or google.com.

My configuration

/etc/dnsmask.conf

```
# Include all files in /etc/dnsmasq.d except RPM backup files
conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d,.rpmnew,.rpmsave,.rpmorig
```

/etc/dnsmask.d/node-dnsmask.conf

```
 server=/in-addr.arpa/127.0.0.1
 server=/cluster.local/127.0.0.1
```

/etc/dnsmask.d/origin-dns.conf

```
no-resolv
domain-needed
no-negcache
max-cache-ttl=1
enable-dbus
dns-forward-max=5000
cache-size=5000
bind-dynamic
except-interface=lo
# End of config
```

/etc/dnsmask.d/origin-upstream-dns.conf

```
server=172.25.250.254
server=192.168.1.1
```

And either dnsmask resolve private name but not public or resolve public but not private :

```
dig index.docker.io -> answer 0
dig node1.lab.example.com -> answer 1
```

And 10 minutes later

```
dig index.docker.io -> answer 3
dig node1.lab.example.com -> answer 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I partially answer my own question

Reading the [dnsmask man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) in the all-servers option

```
--all-servers
By default, when dnsmasq has more than one upstream server available, 
it will send queries to just one server. Setting this flag forces dnsmasq to 
send all queries to all available servers. The reply from the server which 
answers first will be returned to the original requester.
```

it's said that the query will be sent to only one server which explains this situation.

If I add this option the problem seems solved.

However I don't understand what means "the first answer", the first who answers is the the winner or the first with a non-zero answer is the winner ?

If the former is true, the behaviour may be unstable along the time.

Comment: Did you discover if its the first answer or first non-zero answer?